# How can I get my Optimus-addled NVIDIA card to offer output via xrandr?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xrandr, optimus, vulkan

I have a laptop that is crippled with NVIDIA Optimus.  I'm not greatly interested in saving power so I'd be willing to turn on the NVIDIA chip permanently, but my BIOS does not offer that option.  Bumblebee works well enough for many purposes, but I am attempting to try out Vulkan now and that doesn't seem to agree with Bumblebee.  Some people on Reddit or someplace said that a person in my situation should try this instead:  http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/364.19/README/randr14.html

If I understand right, the link says how to configure Xorg to explicitly recognize both the NVIDIA and Intel chips, with xrandr being used to link them together appropriately, so that the one feeds into the other.  It sounds like this strategy removes the need for Bumblebee.

But when I try it, I get a black screen.  Nothing crashes and I can't find any error messages anywhere.  I can still bring up invisible terminal windows and type into them, and if I'm careful enough, I can run commands and log out and stuff.

I ran something like `xrandr --listproviders > log` from an invisible terminal window, and the result was this:

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x2c3 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x45 cap: 0x3, Source Output, Sink Output crtcs: 3 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

It seems telling that the NVIDIA-0 there is neither a Source nor a Sink and has no "outputs".  I feel like maybe I need to fix that?  But I don't know where to go from there, other than buying a different NVIDIA card that isn't as crippled.

(My only purpose here is to become able to run a Vulkan demo, which will presumably mean that I can write my own Vulkan-using programs, so an alternate path to that end would suffice as well.)

I'm using Arch Linux 4.5.4-1, and it was just freshly installed so most (possibly all?) of the programs being used here (xserver, xrandr) are in recent versions too.  NVIDIA driver version is 364.19.  Desktop is Xfce.  The actual video card is a GeForce GTX 765M.